# ColumnResizeEvent is giving me the wrong width when resizing datatable columns primefaces

Tags: events, primefaces, datatable, resize, width

I use primefaces 5.2 and jsf 2.2.6 and I get a wrong width value in the columnResizeEvent when resizing the columns.

For the datatable I use the attribute resizeMode="expand", because I want to keep the size of the other columns the same when resizing a column.

But the problem is when I want the decrease the width of a column, I get a bigger value than the previous one, even though I decreased the width and even though in the user interface the column appears to have a smaller width as I want it to be.

When I don't use the attribute resizeMode on the datatable, the provided width from the ColumnResizeEvent is correct, but the size of the other columns are changed and I don't want that.

Is there a way to resize a column and keep the sizes of the others and at the same time to get a correct value of the column width?

Comment: Tried a newer version?

Comment: I tried with 5.3 and still not working correctly, the width maybe is calculated based on a absolute position...I want to reduce the width and the event is providing a greater value.

Comment: is it a 'fixed' deviation? Is there a pattern in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seemed that the problem was the widgetVar from the datatable, because I had several tables with the same value in the widgetVar for every single datatable and that's why it had the same clientId, because the same clientId was added to the DOM.

To find out more about the problem and solution, you can visit another post of mine, in which I want to use the same xhtml with a datatable for multiple tabs:

[How to use the same datatable for all the tabs primefaces (resize not working in this case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284870/how-to-use-the-same-datatable-for-all-the-tabs-primefaces-resize-not-working-in?noredirect=1#comment60210168_36284870)